# Snowflake Error- Unsupported Subquery Type

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So I am trying to run some SQL code to snowflake however i keep running into the unsupported subquery error. Essentially I am updating a table from the other tables, but what i dont understand is why does it work in SQL but not in snowflake? and how do i get it to work.

Here is the update with the joins i am attempting to run:

```js
    UPDATE temp SET sale_cancel_refund_credit_date= ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 pay_trx_date FROM ac_payment_detail  
    join ac_payment on pyd_pay_key=pay_key
    and pay_delete_flag=0 
    WHERE pyd_type = 'Return' 
    AND ivd_key = pyd_ivd_key
    AND pyd_ajd_key is null and pyd_void_flag=0  ) 
    WHERE sale_cancel_refund_credit_date IS NULL;
```

Comment: Alias your subquery in Snowflake. Some DBMS's require an alias and some do not. `...and pyd_void_flag=0  ) z...`

Comment: can you alias all your three tables and then all the usages, so the query can be rewritten by a stranger.

Comment: the sort answer is it's appears to be a correlated sub-query, which for really large datasets  (that have no index's, aka Snowflake) can perform very poorly. Thus it needs to be rewritten as a sub-select and join.

Comment: @Isolated snowflake does not need the sub-query to be named/aliased. It's has very limited support for correlated subqueries. The aliases are needed how ever for a human to rewrite the query.

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim Ah, correct, forgot that Snowflake is kind. At any rate, I agree with the other comments too that the query above should have aliases on those joins. Delyura... also, you may be missing a `from`, something like `update table set column  = t.column from (select top 1 column from)...`

Comment: Yeah it made no difference if i added an alias or not. the query works perfectly fine when i make my database smaller (by just selecting top 5) however when i use it on the normal size (14million rows) it gives this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I assume the table aliases based off what appears to be prefixes.

```
 UPDATE temp AS t
    SET t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date = ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 p.pay_trx_date 
    FROM ac_payment_detail as pd
    JOIN ac_payment AS p
        ON pd.pyd_pay_key = p.pay_key
        AND p.pay_delete_flag = 0 
    WHERE pd.pyd_type = 'Return' 
        AND t.ivd_key = pd.pyd_ivd_key
        AND pd.pyd_ajd_key IS NULL 
        AND pd.pyd_void_flag = 0
    ) 
    WHERE t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date IS NULL;
```

and create some data:

```
 create or replace table temp(sale_cancel_refund_credit_date int, ivd_key int);
 create or replace table ac_payment(pay_key int, pay_delete_flag int, pay_trx_date int);
 create or replace table ac_payment_detail(pyd_pay_key int, pyd_type text, pyd_ivd_key int, pyd_ajd_key int, pyd_void_flag int );
 
 insert into temp values
    (20220101, 1),
    (20220102, 2),
    (null, 3),
    (null, 4);
    
insert into ac_payment values
    (10, 0, 20220103),
    (10, 0, 20220104),
    (10, 0, 20220105);
    
insert into ac_payment_detail values
    (10, 'Return', 3, null, 0),
    (11, 'Return', 4, null, 0);
    
 
 
 UPDATE temp AS t
    SET t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date = ( 
    SELECT TOP 1 p.pay_trx_date 
    FROM ac_payment_detail as pd
    JOIN ac_payment AS p
        ON pd.pyd_pay_key = p.pay_key
        AND p.pay_delete_flag = 0 
    WHERE pd.pyd_type = 'Return' 
        AND t.ivd_key = pd.pyd_ivd_key
        AND pd.pyd_ajd_key IS NULL 
        AND pd.pyd_void_flag = 0
    ) 
    WHERE t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date IS NULL;
```

gives:

> Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

So if we rewrite that sub-query like:

```
SELECT pd.pyd_ivd_key, p.pay_trx_date
FROM ac_payment_detail as pd
JOIN ac_payment AS p
    ON pd.pyd_pay_key = p.pay_key
    AND p.pay_delete_flag = 0 
    AND pd.pyd_type = 'Return' 
    AND pd.pyd_ajd_key IS NULL 
    AND pd.pyd_void_flag = 0
```

we get:

| PYD_IVD_KEY | PAY_TRX_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 20,220,103 |
| 3 | 20,220,104 |
| 3 | 20,220,105 |

now we can use ROW_NUMBER to act as the TOP

```
SELECT pd.pyd_ivd_key, p.pay_trx_date
FROM ac_payment_detail as pd
JOIN ac_payment AS p
    ON pd.pyd_pay_key = p.pay_key
    AND p.pay_delete_flag = 0 
    AND pd.pyd_type = 'Return' 
    AND pd.pyd_ajd_key IS NULL 
    AND pd.pyd_void_flag = 0
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by pd.pyd_ivd_key order by null) = 1;
```

given your data was unsorted, the above will give you a random row

| PYD_IVD_KEY | PAY_TRX_DATE |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 20,220,103 |

if you want the "most recent" then

```
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by pd.pyd_ivd_key order by p.pay_trx_date desc) = 1;
```

so now we can put this into the UPDATE:

```
 UPDATE temp AS t
    SET t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date = n.pay_trx_date
    FROM (
        select pd.pyd_ivd_key, p.pay_trx_date
        FROM ac_payment_detail as pd
        JOIN ac_payment AS p
            ON pd.pyd_pay_key = p.pay_key
            AND p.pay_delete_flag = 0 
            AND pd.pyd_type = 'Return' 
            AND pd.pyd_ajd_key IS NULL 
            AND pd.pyd_void_flag = 0
        QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by pd.pyd_ivd_key order by null) = 1
    ) as n
    WHERE t.sale_cancel_refund_credit_date IS NULL 
        AND t.ivd_key = n.pyd_ivd_key;
```

and with cleanly recreated data we get:

| number of rows updated | number of multi-joined rows updated |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |